# Android in app purchase does not returns products detail

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am working on android in app purchase billing api.
I have created an app on api console and uploaded signed apk on play store under alpha testing.
I have added product in product list.
but when query product list it returns blank array.

Code for call product listing -

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true,mList,mGotInventoryListener);
}
```

and code of inventory finish listener is -

```
  public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");

 }
```

this method always return product list blank.
any one can please help me i am facing problem is this topic from last 3 days.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How mList looks like?

Comment: it is  a list of ids of products on play store,that i have to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

After westing alote of time i was found solution of my problem.
I was just forget to publish my App,i was thinking that it does not require to publish in Alpha testing but i was wrong.